# What is the least possible value of $n$ such that $n^2+n+17$ is composite?

Tags: number-theory

The question is-

> Find the least $n$ for which $n^2+n+17$ is composite.

I tried to factorize it and show that it has a factor greater than $1$.But I could not factorize it and I also found that it has no real zeroes (roots).Now,how do I solve the problem?

Thanks for any help!!

Comment: Does $n$ have to be positive?

Comment: @KennyLau Yes....preferebly...

Comment: Obviously, the least $n$ is at most $17$. So, where is the problem?

Comment: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=table%5BprimeQ%5Bx%5E2%2Bx%2B17%5D,%7Bx,1,17%7D%5D

Comment: @MooS: Even better would be $n^2+n+17=n(n+1)+17$, so the least $n+1$ is at most $17$.

Answer (score -2):

According to computer:

1. $19$ is prime.
2. $23$ is prime.
3. $29$ is prime.
4. $37$ is prime.
5. $47$ is prime.
6. $59$ is prime.
7. $73$ is prime.
8. $89$ is prime.
9. $107$ is prime.
10. $127$ is prime.
11. $149$ is prime.
12. $173$ is prime.
13. $199$ is prime.
14. $227$ is prime.
15. $257$ is prime.
16. $289 = 17\times17$.

Comment: @Downvoter: can you explain why you downvoted?

Comment: I think even the OP knows how to use brute force